# How can I give different arguments in an abstract method?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overloading, abstract

I have an abstract class and an abstract setter method, which takes `String` as an argument but I would like the setter of one of my subclasses to take another type of argument.

I would like to do this without using Generics.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you mean "generics" rather than "collections"?

Comment: Yes, you are right. i am confused, i meant generics.

Answer (score 3):

You can **overload** the setter in the subclass:

```
@Override
public void setProperty(String firstArg) {
   ...
}

public void setProperty(Integer value) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would *like* to do this without generics, but I think you need them:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> {
    public abstract void setX(T t);
}

public class MySubClass extends MyClass<String> {
    public void setX(String s) {
    }
}

public class MySpecialSubClass extends MyClass<Integer> {
    public void setX(Integer s) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure - it depends. With the other answer, if you have a variable declared as the abstract class, the compiler won't know it's an instance of the special subclass, so an overloaded method won't be accessible. You would have to declare the variable as being of the special subclass to "see" the overloaded method. Mind you, this answer isn't much better, because you'd still have to know the type of the parameter, but at least you wouldn't have to know what the implementing class is. This answer is more decoupled from the implementation, which is always a good thing.